# error al guardar el contenido de textbox.text en ASP

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net, text

esta pregunta puede ser muy basica, pero ya llevo horas de horas intentando corregir el error. hice un formulario web en ASPX y c# donde el usuario autenticado puede editar sus datos como nombre, apellidos, correo electrónico, incluso cambiar su contraseña de acceso. no tengo problemas con la autenticacion, manejar la sesion o incluso cambiar la contraseña. todo eso ya funciona. lo que no funciona es cambiar el nombre y apellidos, o el correo electronico. en teoria es muy sencillo guardar el dato del textbox.text, pero el problema es que no lo guarda, mantiene el dato cargado previamente. al cargar la pagina, se cargan los datos actuales del usuario, y la idea es que los pueda cambiar, pero no guarda el dato cambiado, solo el actual. por ejemplo, si me llamo Jose Hernandez Rojas y cambio a Jose Rojas Hernández, me mantiene el primer dato, no el cambiado. les muestro el codigo ASPX. Importante indicarles que uso un siteMater para la interface general

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <td>
            </td>
        <td >
        <div style="max-width: 400px;">
       
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Mi perfil</h2>
        <asp:Label Text="Nombre completo" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtFullname"/>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFullname" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese su nombre completo" required="required"/>
        <br/>
        <asp:Label Text="Nombre de usuario" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtUsername"/>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username" required="required" Enabled="False"/>
        <br/>
        
        <asp:Label Text="Correo electrónico" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtEmail"/>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" TextMode="Email" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email" required="required"/>
                    <br/>

        <hr/>
            <a href="ChangePassword.aspx" role="button" class="btn btn-primary">Cambiar la contraseña</a>
            
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="btnSignup" runat="server" Text="Modificar mis datos" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btnSignup_Click"/>
    </div>
            </td>

        <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

este es el codigo .CS de este sitio, donde muestro que al hacer clic en el botón se dispara la accion de actualizar los datos. el comando SQL funciona correctamente, pero el dato que me devuelve el txtFullname.text no cambia, y esa es mi duda. ya intente poner la propiedad AutoPostBack="true" en los textbox, pero no hay cambio

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace User_Login_CS
{
    public partial class myProfile : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            if (!this.Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
            }

            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from users where Username='" + this.Page.User.Identity.Name + "';", con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            txtFullname.Text = reader["Fullname"].ToString();
                            txtUsername.Text = reader["Username"].ToString();
                            txtEmail.Text = reader["Email"].ToString();
                            int tipo = Convert.ToInt32(reader["RoleId"]);
                        }
                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
            }


        }
        
        protected void btnSignup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Users SET Fullname='" + txtFullname.Text + "',Email='" + txtEmail.Text + "' WHERE Username='" + txtUsername.Text + "'", con))
                {
                    string message = string.Empty;
                    try
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                        message = "Usuario actualizado";
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        message = "Ha habido un error";
                    }
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + message + "');", true);
                }

            }
        }

        protected void txtFullname_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string nombre = txtFullname.Text;
        }

        protected void txtEmail_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string correo = txtEmail.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

como ven, incluso intente con el evento TextChanged pero tampoco funciono.

alguna otra idea?? ya llevo mucho tiempo y no lo logro. gracias!!

Comment: ¿La base de datos registra la actualización, es decir, si los cambios se aplicaron en la base de datos? Supuestamente no deberían haberse aplicado. Puedes confirmar

Comment: no se aplican ya que desde el sitio web no sale ningun cambio. como dije, en el modulo de cambio de password si se hace el cambio ya que al cargar la pagina, los campos de texto Password y ConfirmPassword entran vacios. en este modulo, los campos cargan la info actual del usuario. necesito que al modificarlo en el form, se haga en la BD, pero al inspeccionar el TXTFullname.text no hay ningun cambio

Comment: Lo que sucede es que el el Page_Load siempre cargas los datos del usuario. Cuando le das el btnSignup se ejecuta primero el Page_Load y luego el BtnSignup, pero el page restaura los datos del usuario y es por eso que siempre vez los antiguos. Para solucionarlo encierra el bloque donde cargas los datos del usuario con un if: `if (!IsPostBack()) { ... String constr.... Using ... } } de modo tal que los datos del usuario se carguen la primera vez que entras a la página.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich sos genial, funciono de maravilla. gracias!!

Comment: Lo pongo como respuesta para que la apruebes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que en el `Page_Load` siempre cargas los datos del usuario. Cuando le das el `btnSignup` se ejecuta primero el `Page_Load` y luego el `btnSignup`, pero en `Page_Load` siempre cargas los datos del usuario y es por eso que siempre vez los antiguos.

Para solucionarlo encierra el bloque donde cargas los datos del usuario con un if:

```
if (!IsPostBack()) { 

     String constr.... 
     Using ... }
}
```

El `!IsPostBack` es para asegurar que se ejecute siempre que la página se cargue por primera  o que no venga de una acción dentro de sí misma.